# ACPI BIOS Error (bug) error logs in kernal.log ubuntu-20.10

Tags: ubuntu-20.10

I am using ubuntu 20.10
My device memory got full in just 10 days from 250 gb to 100 gb
when i looked into logs i found **kern.log** file which has a storage of about 50 gb
I looked into many solutions but none of them seems to be working for me .
I get errors like below

```
eb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.226498] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_L6F]
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.226499] No Arguments are initialized for method [_L6F]
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.226500] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L6F due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.226504] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20200528/evgpe-511)
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.228423] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_GPE._L6F.PGRT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.228428] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_L6F]
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.228428] No Arguments are initialized for method [_L6F]
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.228430] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L6F due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
```

Kernal which i use **5.8.0-41-generic**
Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't a [good fit for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is more suited for https://askubuntu.com/, so try posting it there, but make sure to comply with their [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) rules.

Comment: Sure I will give a try @costaparas
Thanks for the suggestion .